# mysql select event as multiple records

Tags: mysql

how can i select event in multiple records as days in resultset

Example:

```
id     |     event    |     dateFrom            |       dateTo
1           festival     2012-06-15 01:18:00        2012-06-17 01:18:00
```

Result:

```
id    |  date
1       2012-06-15 
1       2012-06-16
1       2012-06-17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Best way is to make a simple table filled with all the dates of a year.
I made a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root_extern'@'%' PROCEDURE fill_calendar 
(
  IN  start_date  date,
  IN  end_date    date
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date DATE;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO `calendar` (`date`) VALUES (crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END|
```

Your query will look like:
`SELECT date FROM calendar WHERE date BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo`

Answer (score 0):

Use a union like this:

```
(SELECT id, dateFrom date FROM table) UNION (SELECT id, dateTo date FROM table)
```